# Weird rainbow colored chromatic aberration

Tags: chromatic-aberration

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]
[image: Example 4]

This is some weird chromatic aberration that I'm seeing with my Canon 6D with a 24-105mm IS f/4L
lens. The first picture is where the sun is setting to my right. The second example is where the sun is setting to my left.

Can anybody shed some light on why this is occurring? Could it be a problem with my camera or lens. I recently upgraded from a Rebel XS.

Also, I'm not using any filters.

The last image is the result of an HDR merge (no post proc)

Comment: Were these shot at a high ISO setting? Also, are you presenting them as they came out of the camera (and not subject to post processing to push exposure)?

Comment: ISO 100, these are 7 bracketed shots merged, but even the individual raw files show this aberration. It is only intensified when I merge them. I've attached an unprocessed jpeg of the RAW file above. I have not altered the exposure in post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's certainly nothing wrong with your lens, or camera for that matter. This doesn't look anything like a lens based chromatic aberration, but instead it looks like an image processing issue.

My best guess (without having access to the original images) is that saturation has been pushed too far, and the result is certain colour channels are hitting their maximum value and topping out, which results in a sudden shift in hue as that channel stops getting any brighter.

Colours in a digital image lose saturation the brighter they get (there's no such thing as a more saturated white), so you have to choose between very light colours or very strong colours. Try reducing the overall image brightness, or try increasing saturation of the foreground independently of the sky.

Comment: The last image is the result of an unprocessed HDR merge in photoshop (without any correction, color modification). The second image from the last is an unedited shot (+2 of the 7 bracketed shots).

Comment: The phenomenon is known as "banding", where gradients show abrupt shifts

Comment: @MattGrum and David Rouse, thanks very much for the insight. Turns out Photoshop CC mucks up HDR merges (or I don't know how to use it). The images don't exhibit this banding when I merge the bracketed shots using Photomatix.

Answer (score 1):

Are you shooting in JPG or RAW?  I used to get this banding effect when I used to shoot in JPG.  I switched to shooting in RAW and have not had that problem since. RAW provides much more digital info for your photo.

Comment: These are all raw images.